# i just started JavaScript. i have added jquery library to my html page but this is not working

Tags: javascript

my heading is supposed to be hidden but this is not working.

```
<head>
    <title>jquery adding</title>
    <script src = "jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id = "heading1">Kamran Arshad</h1>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("heading1").hide();   
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: is this a valid path in src ?

Comment: `$("#heading1").hide();`..Read about `selectors`...

Comment: Have you put your jquery file inside the same folder where your this html file is placed? I guess, no.

Comment: And what `$(function() {...})` wrapper is supposed to mean? May be that should be `(function($) {...})(jQuery)`? Anyway, the script `jQuery("#heading1").hide();` would do; or may be you'll need `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#heading1").hide(); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong selector. Use:

```
$("#heading1")
```

This is an ID selector, opposed to the element selector you have.

Here are the different types of selectors:

```
$("h1")
```

This selects all h1 elements and is an element selector, not prefixed by anything.

```
$(".apples")
```

This is a class selector used for selecting classes on elements.

```
$("#apples")
```

This is an ID selector selecting an ID from an element.

In your case, you have an h1 element with the id of heading1. Use the ID selector.

Also I would make sure that you have the jquery file in the same folder as this html file and make sure it is named and referenced correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You must include a valid path to a jquery src file. Using your path, you would have to have the jquery file in the same folder as this html file is located.

Also, your selector is wrong. Use $("#heading1"), not $("heading1")

```js
        $(function() {
            //$("heading1").hide();
          $("#heading1").css("color","red");
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="heading1">Kamran Arshad</h1>
```